# Scala don't do in case at least one exist

Tags: scala

What is the most Scala way solution for an algorithm for don't do in case at least one exists?

For example, in Java I would do:

```
private void handle(Event event, AnotherEvent anotherEvent) {

    boolean alreadyExists = false;

    for (AnotherEvent existingEvent: anotherEvent.events()) {
        if (existingEvent.isSame(event)) {
            alreadyExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!alreadyExists) {
        //do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `exists(predicate: A => Boolean)` that is defined on every `Iterable`:

```scala
if (!anotherEvent.events().exists(_.isSame(event))) {
  //do
}
```